# some bug in FireFox polymer.dart | dart2js

Tags: firefox, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, social-likes

Could you please help me to detect and fix same bug in the simple Click Counter application.

I generated the Click Counter application from Dart Editor (New project -> simple web application using polymer library..)

Now I want to add Social Likes functionality (see http://sapegin.github.io/social-likes/.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample app</title>

    <!-- include the web_components polyfills with support for Dart. -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>

    <!-- import the click-counter -->
    <link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cc.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="social-likes_birman.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="social-likes.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Cc</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
    </div>

    <div class="social-likes">
      <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
      <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
      <div class="plusone">Google+</div>
    </div>

    <!-- bootstrap polymer -->
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code works perfect in Dartium and Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox (the styles of Social Likes is not applied! The web console of FireFox doesn't contain any error..

Dart Editor version 1.7.0.dev_04_06 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.7.0-dev.4.6
Firefox 33

The code of application is attached to this issue.

I really don't understand what is wrong. Is there a bug in FireFox or polymer or dart2js? This bug is very critical for me...

Comment: Have you tried it without Dart (just a plain HTML page)?

Comment: Yes, the plain HTML page works perfect in FireFox

Comment: You can check which changes the Polymer transformer applies by comparing the generated output with the source files. I can't see anything in your code that would cause problems but I also have never tried using Polymer.dart with jQuery, maybe there is some collision.

Comment: I created issue https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21353